# Loading custom module base on context in server side SuiteScript 2.0

Tags: lazy-loading, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I'm trying to load my custom module base on the condition.

```
CustomModule.js

define([], function(){
  export {
    run: function(){ log.debug('run in CustomModule' }
  };
}
```

And here is my user event script

```
userevent.js

define(['N/record'], function(record){
  ...
  var moduleName = record.getValue('custom_module_name'); // will return CustomModule.js
  require([moduleName], function(customModule){
    customModule.run();
  });
});
```

But I got following error

```
{
   type: "error.SuiteScriptModuleLoaderError",
   name: "INCORRECT_SUITESCRIPT_CONFIGURATION",
   message: "Incorrect SuiteScript configuration for module: CustomModule.js",
}
```

When I using preload like `define(['CustomModule.js'), function(customModule){...})`
is working, but this might not suitable for our scenario.

Any suggestion?

Comment: For anyone who looking for answer: use absolute path will work. `require(['SuiteScripts/custom_lib.js'], (lib) => {})`

Answer (score 0):

So the way you would call a custom module would be (sample snippets below):

**CustomModule.js [Code in file cabinet]**

```
define([], function() {
    // You can have multiple functions
    function testFunction() {
        log.debug("Run in CustomModule");
        return 123;
    }
    return {  // Return all your functions here
        testFunction: testFunction
    };
});
```

And the way you would call the custom module functions in other scripts would be:

**Sample User Event Script:**

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define(['./CustomModule.js'], function(customModule) {
    .....
    function sampleFunction(customerId, recId, invNumberCounter) {
        var storeNumber = customModule.testFunction();  // value of 'storeNumber' will be 123
    }
    .....
});
```

**Additional Important Note:** 
When writing library scripts (custom modules), have the client-side supported modules in a different script and server-side supported modules in a different script. 
This is because, if you incorporate a library script that has a module which is supported only by server-side scripts (eg. N/task module) into a client script, an error would be thrown saying that the module is not supported in this scrpt.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can only include modules supported by both client and server in the define function.

To include functionality which utilizes server-side modules, write the server side function to include a parameter for the required module, and pass the module when calling the function.

For example, if you are calling a common function from a Suitelet, and your common function uses *serverWidget*, design the function to take *serverWidget* as a parameter or as a property of the object you're passing in.

```
// sample server-side function definition included in your custom module
const buildSublist = (scriptContext, serverWidget, sublistData)=>{
  // Make use of NetSuite server-side modules.
  // Only call this function from server-side contexts.
};
```